# PHP CURL - Passing an image from a remote url with http header response code checking in one curl resource

Tags: php, curl

I have php application that serve image, the image is coming from a remote URL and passing it to the browser with content type image. My code has 2 steps:

1. Using curl to check the http header response. If it is a valid image (httpcode 200).
2. if httpcode is 200, I used readfile function with header content-type: image/jpg.

For me the approach above is not a good idea because it makes 2 http hit. My goal is to make the 2 steps above just one using CURL. Is it possible?

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using `readfile` without verifying, and handling the error for `readfile`?

Comment: Can you not just use an img tag and refernce the image directly in the page?

Comment: I need to verify if the image exist because 1 requirement is to give the alternative image if the first image do not exist. Using readfile it self doesn't give me information about the http header. I forgot to mentioned that I am also getting the last-modified, etag and the file size of the remote URL and passing it to the browser

Comment: It needs to be content-type: image/jpg, because clients are downloading the image.

Comment: Instead of CURL, you can use [get_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).